# Spring JPA JSON to model mapping doesnt map to the right column

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

So I was following [this tutorial](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-mvc/spring-jpa-postgresql-angularjs-example-spring-boot) to learn Spring with JPA as REST API and perform CRUD operations. I defined a table in my PostgreSQL with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.customer
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  firstname character varying(50),
  lastname character varying(50)
);
```

When I am trying to create a new customer using the following codes, the customer is created but instead of inserting the `firstname` and `lastname` data into the respective fields, it inserts the data into new columns named `first_name` and `last_name`. How does this mapping take place?

Controller - **BaseController.java:**

```
// all imports
@RestController
public class BaseController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/postcustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postCustomer(@RequestBody Response request) {
        request.getData().forEach((data) -> {
            repository.save(data.getCustomer());
        });
    }
}
```

JSONMapping - **Response.java:**

```
// all imports
public class Response implements Serializable {
    private String status;
    private List<Data> data;
    public Response(String status, List<Data> data) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
    }
    public Response() {
    }
    //all getter setters below
}
```

JSON Mapping - **Data.java:**

```
// all imports
public class Data implements Serializable{
    @JsonProperty("Customer")
    private Customer customer;
    public Data() {
    }
    public Data(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    // all getter setters
}
```

Model - **Customer.java:**

```
// all imports
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009157732242241606L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @JsonProperty("firstname")
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastname")
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;
    protected Customer() {
    }
    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    // all getter setters
}
```

Repository - **CustomerRepository.java:**

```
// all imports
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

}
```

JSON being sent:

```
{
    "status": "Done",
    "data": [ {
        "Customer": {
            "firstname" : "test",
            "lastname" : "123"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: It can't happen, unless the Column annotation you're using is not javax.persistence.Column.

Comment: In your code nothing seems to be like first_name, last_name so please try to drop existing columns from the table and try to create table again using ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because Spring JPA uses its own default naming convention.
Just put following line in application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: i.e Spring subverts the JPA spec (as has been said on other posts in SO). The JPA spec has gone to the trouble of DEFINING the standard column name, and Spring promptly throws away portability. Use it at your peril ...

Comment: Works! Also, I added this property to my application.properties to generate the ddl automatically. `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`